# Variation on $\prec\prec$

Tags: math-operators

Is there a standard TeX or LaTeX code for a symbol that bears the same relation to  `\prec\prec` that `\ll` bears to `<<` ?

(And how do I get TeX code to get rendered in a question posted here?  I'm accustomed to writing things like `$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$` on math.stackexchange.com and having it look the way you'd expect it to.)

Comment: We don't use MathJax here, because we're interested in TeX code, not in an approximate representation of the result.

Comment: the "doubled" `\prec` is in unicode at Ux2ABB and should tus be in the stix and xits fonts.  whether you will find the visual appearance pleasing isn't assured though; this one's a tough cookie.

Comment: The shape given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198930) is much nicer than what's shown in the answers here, although a better name would be `\Prec`.

Answer (score 9):

You can easily build it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\precprec}{\prec\mathrel{\mkern-5mu}\prec}

\begin{document}
$a\precprec b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's what you get with `-6mu` and `-7mu` respectively, take your pick.

[image]

Comment: Why the wrapper `\mathrel` around the kerning?

Comment: @A.Ellett Without it TeX could break a line after the first `\prec` symbol. Do you consider it a valid reason? `;-)`

Comment: Wouldn't `\mathrel{\prec\kern-5mu\prec}` work fine, too?

Comment: @tohecz Why doing it the wrong way? `;-)`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you want.

```
\newcommand\pprec{\prec\mkern-5mu\prec}
```

Then

```
$\pprec$
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Better than nothing, but I think I'd rather have two non-contiguous parts, as happens with \ll.

Comment: So just changing -8 to about -5 would make them non-contiguous.

Comment: I wonder if it would be better to make the shape of the one on the right a bit different from that of the one on the left, so that it doesn't get so close at the leftmost point but gets closer than it now does at other points.