# Double \prec as a single symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

We have `<` and `\ll`. What about double `\prec`, i.e. something like `\prec\prec` but with spacing as in `\ll`?

Remark. I could not find an answer in http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html or http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/. I am not interested, how to construct this symbol from two `\prec`'s (I know how to reduce the distance), but I am searching for a symbol from some package, even so strange as `MnSymbol`.

Comment: STIX Math (or XITS Math), Asana Math and Lucida Bright Math have it (U+2ABB); probably also Cambria Math. It's not included in the TeX Gyre Unicode math fonts.

Comment: @egreg Your comment is a valuable answer for me, so transforming it into an answer would be probably useful for next seekers.

Comment: This question and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149052/variation-on-prec-prec do seem to have quite a bit of overlap: would it be OK to merge? I'd hope that some of the answers will be useful to you and I can see that both questions do seem to cover the 'single symbol' part at least in principle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `mathb` font (from `mathabx`) has an `\llcurly` and a `\ggcurly` symbols. Here is how to use them without loading the whole package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathb5 <6-7> mathb6 <7-8> mathb7
<8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9
<10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\llcurly}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"CE}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ggcurly}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"CF}
\begin{document}

\[ a \llcurly b \quad a \ggcurly b \]

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, "parallel" curved lines look much better then a simple translation of `\prec`!

Comment: Is this line really necessary: \def\blueDiamond{\mathbin{\color{SteelBlue3}\blacklozenge}} ?

Comment: @Rauni: That's right. I think I took the preamble from a previous code for an answer to a more less related question and forgot to check what had to be deleted. It's removed now. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: According to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218683/23484, it should be "mathb5", not "mathab" (right after <-6>).

Comment: I've seen that, and corrected the mistyping.

Answer (score 4):

The unicodes are [U+2ABB](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2abb/index.htm) and [U+2ABC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2abc/index.htm). Here are some examples with the fonts I am having available (in order of increasing uglyness):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand*{\test}{\ensuremath{\prec\Prec\Succ\succ}}

\begin{document}
    \setmathfont{code2000.ttf}\test

    \setmathfont{xits-math}\test

    \setmathfont{asana-math}\test

    \setmathfont{quivira.otf}\test

    \setmathfont{symbola.ttf}\test

    \setmathfont{MathCadUniMath.otf}\test

    %\setmathfont{cambria-math}\test % not on my system
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a homemade construction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\pprec{\mathrel{\scalebox{.9}[1]{$\prec$}\mkern-5mu%
  \scalebox{.4}[1]{$\prec$}\mkern-5.5mu\scalebox{.4}[1]{$\prec$}}}
\begin{document}
$a \pprec b$
\end{document}
```

[image]