# Loading symbol from mathb font does not work when document class is amsart

Tags: fonts, symbols, article, amsart

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198902/double-prec-as-a-single-symbol) I found out how to load a "double prec" as a single symbol.

For some reason, this code does not work when the documentclass is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsart}
```

Minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\pagestyle{plain}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathab <6-7> mathb6 <7-8> mathb7
<8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9
<10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\llcurly}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"CE}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ggcurly}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"CF}

\def\blueDiamond{\mathbin{\color{SteelBlue3}\blacklozenge}}

\begin{document}
\[ a \llcurly b \quad a \ggcurly b \]
\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

> ...
>
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")Running miktex-makemf.exe...
>      miktex-makemf: The mathab source file could not be found.
>
> Running hbf2gf.exe...
>
> hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.3)
>
> Couldn't find `math.cfg'
>
> miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font mathab.
>
> ! Font U/mathb/m/n/5=mathab at 5.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
>        
>                          relax 
>      l.21 \begin{document}
>
> ?

If I change the documentclass line to

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
```

then PDF is generated successfully (with the following output):

> ...
>
> Running miktex-mf.exe...
>
> This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (MiKTeX 2.9)
>
> ...
>
> Font metrics written on mathb10.tfm.
>
> Output written on mathb10.300gf (250 characters, 26804 bytes).
>
> Transcript written on mathb10.log.
>
> METAFONT failed for some reason
>
> ignoring 0 strange path(s)
>
> [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/conf
>       ig/pdftex.map}] (C:\temp\artikkel_doubleprec_test.aux)Trying to make PK font mathb10 at 657 DPI...
>
> Creating mathb10.pk...
>
> Running miktex-mf.exe...
>
> This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (MiKTeX 2.9)
>
> ...

Why does it not work with document class `amsart`?

Comment: Even with the `article` class, `makemf` shouldn't be launched, as it will produce bitmap fonts. Did you install `mathabx-type1` and did you run `updmap` (both as administrator and as user)?

Comment: After fixing according to @David, makemf is not called any more.

Comment: Ah! Fine. It happens from time to time that MiKTeX installs a type 1 font without refreshing `dvips.map` and friends. One then has to run `updmap` manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest font should be `mathb5` not `mathb` (error in the original but not triggered in the original document)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\pagestyle{plain}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathb5 <6-7> mathb6 <7-8> mathb7
<8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9
<10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\llcurly}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"CE}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ggcurly}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"CF}

\def\blueDiamond{\mathbin{\color{SteelBlue3}\blacklozenge}}

\begin{document}
\[ a \llcurly b \quad a \ggcurly b \]
\end{document}
```