# How to invert a mathematical operator?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

How can I invert a mathematical operator about an imaginary vertical axis that runs through the symbol's center? Specifically, consider the symbol `\prec`, which resembles the less-than symbol `<`. I'd like to create an analogous version that is to the greater-than symbol `>` as `\prec` is to `<`. How can I do so?

I'm looking for an answer that I will be able to easily modify to various symbols other than `\prec`. In particular, besides `\prec` I'm currently interested in inverting the symbols `\preceq` as well as the following custom-made symbol:

```
\newcommand{\pprec}{\mathbin{{\prec}\mspace{-5mu}{\prec}}}
```

that is to `\ll` as `\prec` is to `<`.

Comment: Did you try `\reflectbox` from `graphicx`?

Comment: `\succ` ?......

Comment: Look also at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198902/

Comment: Can't you use `\succ` and similar in this case

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\mathrel`? Better yet, `\prec\mathrel{\mspace{-5mu}}\prec`

Comment: `\succ` and `\succeq` exist.

Comment: @egreg: I don't think this is a duplicate, since I asked a general question, the answer to which should be applicable even to symbols that do not already have a ready-made inverted version. Nevertheless, since I'm currently only interested in the three versions of `\prec` that I mentioned in my post, I won't press this matter further.

Comment: @EvanAad Then ask it for a generic symbol, not for one that's already provided. But there are few nonsymmetric symbols that already haven't the reflected version available.